# UDP Sockets - Client Packet Receiving Exception

Tags: c#, .net, networking, udp

I've made this UDP client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace UDP_Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program go = new Program();
            go.Client();
        }
        void Client()
        {
            byte[] msg = new byte[1000];
            Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            IPEndPoint x = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 12345);
            IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            int PacketSize = sck.Receive(msg); // <- The exception is thrown here, when the client tries to receive a packet
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

So, the problem is, whenever I try to receive a message with the client, it throws a SocketException (an invalid argument was supplied).

What is the problem here? Did I forget to do something before the receive?

And I won't use Bind here, since it's a client and not a server.

Comment: If your intent is to receive, then you need to bind.

Comment: But it is a client, not a server. If I'm already running a server on my computer, and I open up a client, I can't bind both of them. I can bind only one of them. So how can I receive messages on the client side?

Comment: If you're already bound to a certain port, your client can't also receive on that port. You need to bind to a different port or use a different PC.

Comment: Also, in the code you posted, it appears you're not using `x` and `sender`...

Comment: OK, I found a solution, and I'm sorry, but I think you might be wrong. Now when I used the Receive method after using the SendTo method, everything works just fine. I simply added a SendTo before the Receive and it works. Also, the x and sender variables are reserved for later use. Thank you anyway.